# Licence of this dictionary file

Tags: bsd

What is the licence of this dictionary file https://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?revision=61569&view=markup . Is it also BSD or some else?

Comment: Can anyone tell what li cense is this.https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/tree/master/share/dict.

Answer (score 2):

According to the note in the accompanying README file, the copyrights on the wordlist have expired.

Copyrights expire after a certain time, which is different for each country. For natural persons, copyrights typically expire some 50 to 70 years after the death of the copyright holder. For businesses and other legal entities, copyrights typically expire some 50 to 70 years after the publication of a work.

When the copyrights on a work expire, then the work comes into the public domain and can be used in just about any way.

Comment: nice. Went throgh those files trying fing some copyright notice but did not read the README.